# Padding to the right side of row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a design with twitter bootstrap 2 (responsive). In this design, I have a header, left sidebar, content and footer.

Basically, I have the following code structure - have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/w4yh9/3/

The important section is the:

```
<div id="inner" class="span10">
...
</div>
```

Please have a look at the attached screenshot, especially the yellow marked area:

[image: Padding problem]

I have the following question / problem:
How can I add some padding to the right for all content elements (success message, content, table) - it should work on smaller screens as well?

Comment: post your notification css.

Comment: I suspect you want right padding on your `#inner` but you haven't given us much to go on...

Comment: In my sample, haven't changed any twitter css code (except some custom color/background css-commands)

Comment: please post the css responsible for your question.

Comment: Ok, I have build now an jsfiddle example for better understanding and updated my question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the parent container a padding and also apply box-sizing: border-box to it.
Check out my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4yh9/4/

```
#main {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.span10 {
    padding-right: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your hint was great. Using ".span10 {padding-right: 10px; box-sizing: border-box;}" and some mediaqueries solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
#main {padding-right:5px}
```

But maybe that makes `#main` wider than you'd like.

In that case, you could use

```
#main > div { width:98%; }
#main > .navbar {width:100%; }
```

to set all children divs of main to 98% width, and then over-ride this for the (hopefully limited number of) specific children that you want to be full-width.